# Can we permanently fixed HTML page and cannot edit again?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-web-developer

i want that no one can edit or change my html file especially on browser ???

Try new tips & tricks and get more knowledge about web-development and website design..

want to know more ab HTML , CSS , JAVASCRIPT , PHP , C# , SQL , PYTHON....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this by disabling right click
*Disable Right-Click:*
While this won't prevent experienced users from modifying your HTML, it can deter casual users. You can add a script to disable the right-click context menu, making it more challenging for users to view or edit the page source.

```
 html
   <script>
     document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
     });
   </script>
```

Keep in mind that this is not foolproof and can be bypassed easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick solution that stops your friends from changing the site's HTML by inspecting the page, you can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

The following example shows how you can detect when the page's HTML has been updated:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    console.log('stop');
  })

  observer.observe(document.body, {
    characterData: true,
    childList: true,
    attributes: false,
    subtree: true
  });
})
```

```html
<h2>Open Dev Tools and Edit</h2>
<p>Lists can be nested (list inside list):</p>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to revert the change when the HTML is updated, a dirty solution would be to store the body's `innerHTML` on load, then replace on change.

This is mostly a for-fun thing though - don't use this on a real site, since completely overwriting `innerHTML` will break your site. This is because you are essentially destroying every element and recreating it, causing previously bound event listeners to be lost.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const startHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
  const observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    if(document.body.innerHTML != startHTML){
      alert('nice try bro');
      document.body.innerHTML = startHTML;
    }
  })

  observer.observe(document.body, {
    characterData: true,
    childList: true,
    attributes: false,
    subtree: true
  });
})
```

```html
<h2>Open Dev Tools and Edit</h2>
<p>Lists can be nested (list inside list):</p>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```